# Subtracting an integer from an integer in a stored procedure (SQL version 8.0.23)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to decrease an integer from an integer in a stored procedure but
I don't get the result I want.

I have the following tables:

Table h(

i int
c int )

that holds values

| i | c |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |

Table k(

j int
c int
d text
e timestamp)

that holds values

| j | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | NULL | NULL |

I've written the following code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS a;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE a(b int, c int, d text, e timestamp)
BEGIN
DECLARE f INT;
SELECT c INTO @f FROM h WHERE i = j;
START TRANSACTION;
CASE WHEN (@f - c) < 0
THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE "45000"
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "@f - c < 0 is not allowed";
WHEN c < 0
THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE "45000"
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "c < 0 is not allowed";
WHEN j NOT IN (select i from h)
THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE "45000"
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "j does not exist";
ELSE
UPDATE h AS l SET c = (@f - c) WHERE j = i;
INSERT INTO k (d) VALUE (d);
INSERT INTO k (e) value (e);        
END CASE;
COMMIT;
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL a (1, 10, "changed -10", "2002-06-27 14:42:33");

SELECT * FROM h;
```

Table k is updated correctly. But Table h is not.
I want to get the following results shown for Table h after
the code above is run.

| i | c |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 90 |

But instead I get

| i | c |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |

What should be changed in my code in order to get the result I want?

Comment: Firstly you execute `SELECT c INTO @g FROM h WHERE i = j;`. Then you perform some IFs. Then you execute `UPDATE h AS l SET c = (@g - c) WHERE j = i;`. taking into account that `@g` is equal `c` in this row, do you really want to see something other than zero?

Comment: PS. **NEVER** interfere columns names and local valiables names (SP parameters are local variables too).

Comment: `SELECT c INTO @g FROM h WHERE i = j;` What is `j`?

Comment: Made a mistake, the variable f is the one that is going to be a local variable @f. I've updated the code now. j is a column in table k.

Comment: `f` (declared local variable) and `@f` (user-defined variable) are two different independent variables.

Comment: @Akina is that not the order I have in the code? I first do SELECT c INTO @f FROM h WHERE i = j; and then perform the CASE-statements and lastly do the UPDATE h AS l SET c = (@f - c) WHERE j = i;

Comment: I understand @Akina. All I want is that the value of c specified in the CALL statement is subtracted from the integer in column c. So if I write ```CALL a (1, 30, "changed -30", "2001-05-27 14:40:33");``` I want to get the value of c in table h to show 70.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
SELECT c INTO @f FROM h WHERE i = j;
```

you select a variable (defined as SP parameter), not a column value !!!

In your call it becomes

```
SELECT 10 INTO @f FROM h WHERE i = j; -- parameter variable `c` gets the value 10.
```

You must use

```
SELECT h.c INTO @f FROM h WHERE i = j;
```

---

Let's me to repeat:

**NEVER** interfere columns names and local variables names (SP parameters are local variables too).

---

Additionally - your SP will fail because it uses non-declared variable `j`. By the parameters meaning/assigned values it must be `b`...